# ToggleButton on Android 6: setCompoundDrawables doesn't work

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-togglebutton

I've this code for put a drawable to the right of a ToggleButton text:

```
ToggleButton myToggle = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.filtro_stat);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a010_ico);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 0.5),
            (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * 0.5));
ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, Utils.dpToPixels(33,
            getActivity()), Utils.dpToPixels(26, getActivity()));

myToggle.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, sd.getDrawable(), null);
myToggle.setTextOn(getActivity().getString(R.string.string_on));
myToggle.setTextOff(getActivity().getString(R.string.string_off));

final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    myToggle.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.blue));
} else {
    myToggle.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.blue));
}
myToggle.setChecked(false);
```

If i run on a device with Android 6, drawable does not appear, else if i run code on old android version, everything works fine. How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how i fixed it:

After you create de ScaleDrawable:

```
drawable = sd.getDrawable();

drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 0.5),
            (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() * 0.5));

myToggle.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, drawable, null);
```